# An add method to add objects in your custom java class

Tags: java

A simple question on Java class

I want to create my class with my own add method which adds an object of a different class.

For eg if my class name is Weapon, I want to create an add method like void add(Gun gun) (Gun being one of my other classes for example)

This would be just like creating your own collection maybe??? if I am not wrong? Like list.add() method, I want to implement my own add method for the Weapon class

So when I instantiate an object of my weapon class, it should be like
Weapon w = new Weapon(new Gun( ... .. constructor parameters) )

Also I would like to have variants of my add methods. Like a different add method with different parameters like void add(Weapon weapon) ( creating an method to add your own class object )

So I am not sure if this is similar to implementing a collection?? And if it is how do I achieve it? Do I have to extend another class for this?

Apologies if my question confused anyone! :)

Comment: definitely confused me.

Comment: You are right, it does confuse me. It is unclear what you are trying to achieve and what your actual problem is. If you want an `add()` method, what stops you from writing one? What does it has to do with collections?

Comment: Just to point out the obvious: `Weapon w = new Weapon(new Gun(...))` doesn't really make sense to me. On the other hand, `Weapon w = new Gun(...)` does.

Comment: Personally, no, it's not, technically `Collection`, unless all the objects you are trying to add are based from a common parent, then it might be, but considering you are trying to provide functionality different objects types, I'd personally avoid it.  Instead, I would use a `List` internally for each type of object you want to included, assuming you can have more than one.

Comment: If the desired behavior of `Weapon` ist not only similar to, but actually the same as the behavior of Collections (as I understood), why do you want to reimplement it? Just reuse the classes the Java API offer. Extending is an option, but also just adding a collection as a class member is easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Object> weapons = new ArrayList<Object>();    

weapons.add(new Sword());     
weapons.add(new Gun());
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have to do a `new Gun()` when you instantiate. You can just do the following:

```
class Weapon
{
    private Gun gun;
    public Weapon()
    {
        gun = new Gun(); //etc.
    }
    //add more methods here. You can use gun.function() to invoke any functions
}
```

As for using a `Weapon` object, just declare public methods in the `Weapon` class and then invoke them in your methods.

For example, the `add()` function:

```
class Weapon
{
    ...
    public int val() { return 0; } // don't know, some random method.
}
```

Then on a different file:

```
int add(Weapon w)
{
    return Weapon.val() + 1111; //perform something here
}
```

I hope this answers your questions, it was a little bit unclear :|. Comment if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear to me, but I'll try my best.

If you want to have a `List` of `Weapon`, then you need to use inheritance. In your example, A `Gun` is-a `Weapon`. Therefore, you can do `class Gun extends Weapon`. Then, let's say you're using an `ArrayList`, you would instantiate it like:

```
List<Weapon> weapons = new ArrayList<Weapon>();
```

You can now call add with a `Gun`, or any other sub-class of `Weapon` like so:

```
weapons.add(new Gun()); //or
weapons.add(new Cannon());
```

If you actually need to add a `Gun` to a `Weapon` (Which doesn't really make sense...), you can use composition. See Shahar's answer for a more detailed explanation of this behavior.

Just to clarify, no matter what, I'm pretty sure creating a new Collection is ***not*** what you want to do here.

Answer (score 0):

These are a lot of questions :-) let's enumerate them

1. creating a method called add() into an object makes this object a Collection? No. To be a Collection, a class must implement the interface java.util.Collection or implement any one of the subinterfaces or extend any of the subclasses that implement this interface. A list of them is available in the Collection javadoc - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html
2. if I want to add an object into another, it must be via the constructor? e.g. new Weapon(new Gun())? Not necessarily. You can just create a Weapon w = new Weapon() and then add the Gun reference via a method such as w.setGun(new Gun()). Anyway, any constructor with one or more parameters must be declared explicitly in your class. Only the non-parameter constructor is available by default.

Now, let's suppose that you want to store a class Gun that is a subclass of a class Weapon. Then you first need to define the hierarchy between them, for example

```
class Weapon{       
}

class WeaponWithBlade extends Weapon{       
}

class Sword extends WeaponWithBlade{        
}

class Knife extends WeaponWithBlade{        
}

class Gun extends Weapon{       
}
```

and then you want to store all these weapons in a Weapon collection.

since all of them are subclasses of the Weapon class, it's valid to do something like this

```
    java.util.List<Weapon> weapons = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    weapons.add(new Sword());
    weapons.add(new Gun());
```

notice that both List and ArrayList are collections (List is an interface and ArrayList is a concrete class that implements the List interface), parametrized to be collections of Weapons.

I hope this can help you.